# Posting JSON with a array object to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

My ViewModel is:

```
public class CFUViewModel
{
public int RID { get; set; }
public int Order { get; set; }
public List<VCItem> VItems{ get; set; }
}
```

where VCItem is:

```
public class VCItem
{
public string Name{ get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I am collecting the data from form elements. Thus,

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
        console.log(gatherData());
        transmitData(gatherData());
});

function gatherData() {
        var vc = dataObject.getVCItems();  
        //This is a knockout function that gives an array of VCItems

        var data = new Object();

        data.RID = $('#rid').val();
        data.VItems = vc;

        return data;

};

function transmitData(dataToSend) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../CFUDashboard/ReceiveData',
            type: 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                  alert('success');
                },
            data: dataToSend
        });
    };
```

In the controller, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceiveData(CFUViewModel viewModel)
{
     //...
}
```

The problem is, though RID is ok, VItems list is not serialized. I suspect, the reason is, the array attached to the JS object is actually string (array wrapped in quotes). This is confirmed by the `console.log(gatherData())`

It is outputted as:

```
VItems : "[{"Name":"OPV3","Category":"FUGY"},{"Name":"OPV7","Category":"FUGX"}]"
```

What is the reason for not getting the list serialized? What am I missing?

Comment: Try to set `traditional: true,` for ajax.

Comment: Set `contentType: 'application/json'` and `data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)`

Comment: I tried both to no avail.

Comment: Show your `getVCItems()` method

Comment: Tried setting `Content-Type` header to `application\json` ?

Comment: When you set data.VCitems do = ko.tojson(vc). Your variable VC is a knockout observable and need to serialise back to Json with the ko.toJSON method.

Comment: `self.getVCItems= function (form) {
            return ko.toJSON(self.vcitems);
        };`

Comment: @MikeB Please see the function getVCItems. I have taken care of getting the JSON from the ko observable.

Comment: Try toJS instead of to JSON ??

Comment: Thanks @MikeB this worked.